# Using `expr()` inside the function

Tags: r, quasiquotes

The [Chapter 19 of Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html) explains that `expr()` is not useful inside the function.

However, in the following case, I could not make a function work without `expr()`.

Let's suppose I want to group a tibble in a function.

```r
data(iris)
iris %>% group_by(Species)
```

The obvious approach is to use "curly curly".

```
func_a <- function(data, grouping) {
  data %>% group_by({{grouping}})
}
func_a(iris, Species)
```

However, "curly curly" does not work if I allow an arbitrarily supplied expressions.

```
func_b <- function(data, ...) {
  data %>% group_by({{...}})
}
func_b(iris, Species)
# Error in (function (x)  : object 'Species' not found
```

In the end, I found I need to `expr()` to make it work.

```r
func_c <- function(data, ...) {
  grouping <- expr(...)
  data %>% group_by(!!grouping)
}
func_c(iris, Species)
```

The example of `expr()` in Advanced R is:

```r
f1 <- function(x) expr(x)
f1(a + b + c)
#> x
```

**My main question is why `func_c` works. Does `expr()` take `...` as it is and evaluate it with `!!`? Why we have to take a different approach for `...`?**

Then, I am not sure why this does not work.

```r
func_d <- function(data, grouping) {
  grouping <- expr(grouping)
  data %>% group_by(!!grouping)
}
func_d(iris, Species)
```

I also checked [rlang manual](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quotation.html), but the explanation is too brief for me.

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want to be able to pass only one column to your group_by or do you want to be able to pass multiple columns? Because I don't think any of your current versions allow for that at the moment. Also you should look into the difference between `enexpr()` and `expr()` when it comes to capturing symbols passed to a function. I'm struggling to answer your question because it's still not clear to me exactly what you are asking. Do you want to hear why each of those functions are wrong or do you just want a working answer?

Comment: I used a single column to consider a simple case, but I found `func_c` failed with multiple columns. To make it work, I had to use `rlang::exprs()` and `!!!` instead of `!!`. Yes, I am still not sure the difference between `enexper()` and `exper()` as you pointed out. In multiple columns case, both `rlang::exprs()` and `rlang::enexprs()` with `!!!` worked. The documentation says the latter is for "expressions supplied by the user of your function," but I don't know why there is no difference in this case.

Comment: @user51966 `expr()` captures the expression provided to it. `enexpr()` captures the expression provided to the "parent" function, instead. `exprs()` and `enexprs()` are list equivalents.

Comment: @ArtemSokolov Thanks. What do you mean by "parent"? For example, `f1` returns `Species` but `f2` raises an error: `f1 <- function(data, ...) { expr(...) } ; f1(iris, Species) ;
f2 <- function(data, ...) { rlang::enexpr(...) } ;f2(iris, Species)`. However, `f3` and `f4` return the same thing. `f3 <- function(data, ...) { rlang::exprs(...) } ; f3(mtcars, gear, carb) ; f4 <- function(data, ...) { rlang::enexprs(...) } ;f4(mtcars, gear, carb)`.

Comment: Use `enxpr` when you have a named parameter: `f2 <- function(data, g) { rlang::enexpr(g) } ;f2(iris, Species)`. `...` work very differently so you dont have to be as careful. Just make sure to use the plurals with `...` to be safe because you never know how many things are in there.

Comment: @user51966 Dots work a little differently than named arguments. In general, [it's best to just pass them directly to tidyverse functions](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/multiple.html#simple-forwarding-of-...) unless you need access to the values inside your function.

Comment: @user51966 The difference between `expr()` and `enexpr()` is best demonstrated without dots. Consider, `f <- function(x) {expr(x)}` and `g <- function(x) {enexpr(x)}`. Calling `f(y)` will return `x` because `x` was passed to `expr()`. Calling `g(y)` will return `y` because `y` was passed to the "parent" function `g`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expr` prevents the evaluation of code. For instance, attempting to run `x` by itself will fail unless `x` is a variable you've previously declared - R will go looking for the value in `x` when you evaluate it, and will issue an error if no such value is found. In contrast, `expr(x)` will never fail (even if `x` hasn't been declared yet), because the `expr` tells R "take this at face value and don't go looking for something else it might represent". `expr(x)` will return something of the type "name", which is basically just that - a name. You can think of a name as the interface between you and R - it's what you type in, and how you communicate your instructions. `eval(expr(x))` is the same as just doing `x`.

Now taking your examples in order:

```
func_c <- function(data, ...) {
  grouping <- expr(...)
  data %>% group_by(!!grouping)
}
func_c(iris, Species)
```

This works because `Species` will be directly passed to `expr` through the `...`, and the return type will be a "name", which gets stored in the variable `grouping`. A name can be evaluated with `!!` as you did it, or with `eval`. Either way, doing `!!grouping` will cause R to first go looking for what the `grouping` variable represents, finding `Species`. The variable gets replaced with its value, and finally `!!Species` will tell R to go looking for the variable called Species, which within the context of the `group_by` function will give you the column called "Species".

Moving on to your next example:

```
f1 <- function(x) expr(x)
f1(a + b + c)
```

This doesn't work simply because `expr(x)` blocks any evaluation. R doesn't go looking for what's inside `x`, so it never finds `a + b + c`, it takes the `x` at face value, and that's what you get.

Finally, we have your last example:

```
func_d <- function(data, grouping) {
  grouping <- expr(grouping)
  data %>% group_by(!!grouping)
}
func_d(iris, Species)
```

This is similar to your first example, but there's an extra variable at play here - the parameter called `grouping`. In your first example, `Species` entered the function directly (through `...`), so it wasn't bound to any parameter name. In this third example, `Species` enters the function through a named parameter, i.e. bound to the variable `grouping`. However, `expr(grouping)` tells R "don't bother looking for what `grouping` represents, I have everything I need right here"... so it never finds `Species` at all. `expr(grouping)` just gives you the name `grouping`, regardless of whatever's in the variable itself. So then when you try to evaluate that using `!!grouping` within `group_by`, R tries to look for a column name called `grouping`... Needless to say, it doesn't find it, and you get a `Column grouping is not found` error.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as `expr()` and `!!` effectively negating each other.

```
func_c <- function(data, ...) {
  grouping <- expr(...)
  data %>% group_by(!!grouping)
}
```

is equivalent to

```
func_c <- function(data, ...) {
  data %>% group_by(...)            # Proper way to handle dots, by the way
}
```

(It's not an exact equivalence, because the former implementation expands dots in `expr`, while the latter does it in `group_by`. But both implementations will produce the same output when a single column symbol is supplied to `...`.)

Likewise,

```
func_d <- function(data, grouping) {
  grouping <- expr(grouping)
  data %>% group_by(!!grouping)
}
```

is equivalent to

```
func_d <- function(data, grouping) {
  data %>% group_by(grouping)         # No column `grouping` in iris
}
```

To get `func_d` working, you need to replace `expr()` with `enexpr()`. This will capture the expression provided to the function, as opposed to the expression `grouping` itself.